# Interactive Docker exec with docker-py

Tags: python, docker, interactive, dockerpy

I'm trying to implement something equivalent to:

```bash
docker exec -it <some_container> /bin/bash
```

Ie. run a command in a container and connect `stdin` and `stdout` of my program to `stdin` and `stdout` of the command.

My reading of [the documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#container-objects) seems to imply that the following should do the job:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
container, = client.containers.list()
container.exec_run(['/usr/local/bin/bash'], stdin=True, tty=True)
```

(There's a single container running `bash:latest`)

But it doesn't seem like the program's `stdin` is connected to that of the `exec`'d command.
The command line just sits there, echoing my input, but not reacting to it in any way.

I've also tried to interact with the raw socket (returned by `exec_run`—not `docker.sock`):

```
_, s = container.exec_run(['/usr/local/bin/bash'], stdin=True, tty=True, socket=True)
s.write('echo hello world')
```

But I'm getting `UnsupportedOperation: File or stream is not writable.`

**Question: What would I have to do to allow the user of my code to interact with the std IO of a command executed in a container using docker-py?**

Comment: Accessing the Docker socket at all requires unrestricted root-level access to the host, and this won't work in other container environments like Kubernetes.  Do you actually need to run a debugging command inside another container; why?  Does it need to be an interactive shell?  If you need to use Docker here, can you run a new container running the single command; without the `exec` debugging tool and without specifically a shell?

Comment: @DavidMaze Not sure I understand your comment: the 'raw socket' I was referring to was the socket returned by `exec_run`, not `docker.sock`. I edited to clarify in case that wasn't clear enough. Re: "debugging command": I don't know why you think that's what I want to do. "echo hello world" is just an example, as I hoped would be obvious.  I want to do what `docker exec -it` does, which is a Docker command in good standing.

Answer (score 0):

The result of exec_run is a socket.SocketIO object. Use its socket's recv(), sendall().

e.g.

```
import docker
import threading
import queue

client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.get('YOUR CONTAINER NAME')
_, sock = container.exec_run(cmd='bash', stdin=True, socket=True)
ch = queue.Queue()

def read():
    while res := sock._sock.recv(4096):
        print(res[8:].decode())

def write():
    while item := ch.get():
        item = item + '\n'
        item = bytes(item, 'utf-8')
        sock._sock.sendall(item)

writer = threading.Thread(target=write)
writer.start()

reader = threading.Thread(target=read)
reader.start()

while cmd := input():
    ch.put(cmd)
    if cmd == 'exit':
        break

sock._sock.close()
ch.put(None)

writer.join()
reader.join()
```